# Hapi.js Limit access only to localhost

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I am having an app built with Hapi/React, that is being served in Nodewebkit.

Application is installed on user PC and run locally. Problem I have is this:
- User runs the application. Some other PC which is on same network can access the applicaiton and use it. For example if I run my application on my PC, and my IP is 192.168.0.5. Other person can enter that IP in the browser and it will be able to use my application.

Previously I have used Express instead of Hapi, and there was a setting that prevents it, limits the connecitons only ot local host.

How do I achieve the same thing in Hapi.js?

This is my Nodewebkit startup file:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "desktop";

var Hapi = require('hapi');
var config = require('./config');
var models = require('./models');

log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
appenders: [
    { type: 'console' },
    { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/project.log', category: 'projects' }        
 ]
 });

logger = log4js.getLogger('projects');
logger.setLevel('ERROR');
logger.setLevel('INFO');

var plugins = [
require('inert'),
require('blipp')
];

const server = new Hapi.Server();
var path = require('path');
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);

server.connection({port: config.server.port});

server.register(plugins, function() {   
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{path*}',
    config: {
        auth: false,
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: './public',
                listing: false,
                index: true
            }
        }
    }
  });
});

server.route(require('./server/config/routes'));
models.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
server.start(function () {        
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[By default, hapi connections listen on the 0.0.0.0 interface](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L178) (all network interfaces including your LAN). You want your service to only be available on your machine, so you should listen on the loopback interface only:

```
server.connection({ port: config.server.port, address: '127.0.0.1' });
```

or

```
server.connection({ port: config.server.port, address: 'localhost' });
```

See more info under the [`server.connection([options])`](http://hapijs.com/api#serverconnectionoptions) docs.

Comment: Just came up with the same question. Great answer, just in time. So, it seems that there's no way to specify several ips, only to create several Hapi servers, isn't it?

Comment: This is at the network interface level, so if you want to limit access to certain IPs you'd probably want to only listen on an interface to which that subnet is connected. Or...you can block them at application level, if you're not the network admin.